# Is it possible to restore a previous GL framebuffer?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, drawing, restore, framebuffer

I'm working on an iPhone app that lets the user draw using GL. I used the GLPaint sample code project as a firm foundation, but now I want to add the ability for the user to load one of their previous drawings and continue working on it.

I know how to get the framebuffer contents and save it as a UIImage. Is there a way for me to take the UIImage and tell GL to draw that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would either:

1) Use glDrawPixels()

2) Load the image into a texture and then render a quad.

Comment: Thanks Michael.

glDrawPixels() is not available on the iPhone, so I went with your second suggestion.

Comment: @Rob Do you have any pointers or places to look to to perform the second suggestion?